# Error logging in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, logging

A very short and straight question: I want to catch the error using try..catch and **log it into a file**. Is this possible in SQL Server 2008?

Any directions, help are welcome.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can.

Just implement try catch as it's described here [TRY...CATCH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) . Error logging can be logged either in application or in sql by writing errors to a table.

If you want to log into a file, you can do that using SQLCLR. Check the answer here

[How to log in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58709/how-to-log-in-t-sql)

There're some similar questions you can check.

[Logging into table in SQL Server trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809659/logging-into-table-in-sql-server-trigger)

[Best Practices - Stored Procedure Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938093/best-practices-stored-procedure-logging)

Another approach is to use [Log4Sql](http://log4tsql.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Why the downvote? The only answer, that brings an example of writing to a file using sqlclr.

Answer (score 1):

View the SQL Server error log by using SQL Server Management Studio or any text editor.

By default, the error log is located at `Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.n\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG` and `ERRORLOG.n` files.

Go through **[Viewing the SQL Server Error Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187885%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) page**

Answer (score 0):

Like this, not exactly to file, but to eventlog, I think writing to file is only possible with CLR procedure:

```
BEGIN TRY
  Do some error
END TRY
Begin CATCh
  Declare @error nvarchar(max) = error_message()+' your data'
  exec master..xp_logevent 50001, @error, 'error'
  --Notify host application
   RAISERROR(@error, 16, 1) 
END CATCH
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'Do'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near 'error_message'.

Comment: @blasto Corrected, but it vas obvious. Isn't it?

Comment: How is this going to work with a ROLLBACK in the Begin Catch ?